# Select 2 columns with PHP PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm pretty new to PHP and PDO and I'm trying to make a simple login system. Now, I'm trying to fetch the id and password from my table to compare with the password that the user input(I'm using one way encryption with salt). So, now the problem is, when I do `$password = $stmt->fetchColumn(1)` only, my login system works. Now when I try to get the `id` by doing `$id = $stmt->fetchColumn(0)` just before `$password`, I cannot login anymore and I get my "Wrong Username/Password" error.

Now I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with the `fetchColumn` but I can't figure it out.

Here's a code snippet that works:

```
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
     //set how pdo will handle errors
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
     //this would be our query.
$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM user_admin WHERE email = :email";

      //prepare the statements
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
     //give value to named parameter :email
$stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();

$password = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

Now the following doesn't work. Notice that this happens when I added the `$id`:

```
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
     //set how pdo will handle errors
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
     //this would be our query.
$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM user_admin WHERE email = :email";

      //prepare the statements
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
     //give value to named parameter :email
$stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();


$id = $stmt->fetchColumn(0); //That's the problem
$password = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your *real* problem? Have you tried out var_dump($id)?

Comment: @itinance yes. The problem as mentioned above, is when I add the $id line I can't login anymore and I get "Wrong Username/Password" error instead of "You are now Logged in"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

> PDOStatement::fetchColumn — Returns a single column **from the next row** of a result set

Each time you call `fetchColumn` it advances to the next row of the result set.

Try using [`PDOStatement::fetch`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead to fetch the entire row as an an array and then accessing the values from there.

```
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$id = $row[0];
$password = $row[1];
```

Comment: Perfect. I understand it better now. Thanks